# Ambiguous Controller Names in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried implementing Phil's Areas Demo in my project

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx.

I appended the Areas/Blog structure in my existing MVC project and I get the following error in my project.

The controller name `Home` is ambiguous between the following types:

```
WebMVC.Controllers.HomeController
WebMVC.Areas.Blogs.Controllers.HomeController
```

this is how my `Global.asax` looks.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapAreas("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        "WebMVC.Areas.Blogs",
        new[] { "Blogs", "Forums" });

    routes.MapRootArea("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        "WebMVC",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });

    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    "Default",   // Route name
    //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",// URL with parameters
    //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
    //            // Parameter defaults
    //);

}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    String assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    String path = new Uri(assemblyName).LocalPath;
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AreaViewEngine());
              RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   // RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);

}
```

If I remove the `/Areas/Blogs` from `routes.MapAreas`, it looks at the Index of the root.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET MVC 2.0, you can include the namespace(s) for your parent project controllers when registering routes in the parent area.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                             
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                          
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
    new string[] { "MyProjectName.Controllers" }
);
```

This restricts the route to searching for controllers only in the namespace you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of WebMVC.Areas.Blogs and WebMVC, use WebMVC.Areas.Blogs and WebMVC.Areas.OtherAreaName. Think of the area name as the namespace root, not an absolute namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure I like that solution. The way the projects are desinged, the main controllers/views folder are clearly their own "Area", they just don't have an assigned name. I'd like for that to continue to function as is.

Comment: You can do this if you configure your route to use "main" as the default area.

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize between multiple controllers with the same name in routing as follows

E.g., I have one controller named HomeController in `Areas/Admin/HomeController` 
    and another in root `/controller/HomeController`
    so I prioritize my root one as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", // Parameter defaults
    id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new [] { "MyAppName.Controllers" } // Prioritized namespace which tells the current asp.net mvc pipeline to route for root controller not in areas.
);
```